# authorize users based on user name but not user roles in shiro.ini

Tags: apache, authentication, cloudera, shiro, hortonworks-data-platform

I connected my ldap account to shiro.ini. Is there a way in which I can configure shiro.ini to have user names instead of user roles.

eg:
Right now this is possible

[urls]

/api/interpreter/** = authc, roles[admin]

but is there a way like below:

[urls]

/api/interpreter/** = authc, users[user1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own filter.  Take a look at `org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.RolesAuthorizationFilter` It should be pretty simple to create.

Though generally speaking, I'd advise against it. Instead map your users to roles/permissions (even if it it outside of your LDAP server).  That way your users are decoupled from your configuration.